# constexpr static std::array<const char *,5> failing to compile with MSVC2013

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class ExternalGeometryExtension
{
public:
    enum Flag {
        Defining = 0,
        Frozen = 1, 
        Detached = 2,
        Missing = 3,
        Sync = 4,
        NumFlags
    };

    constexpr static std::array<const char *,NumFlags> flag2str{{ "Defining", "Frozen", "Detached","Missing", "Sync" }};
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << ExternalGeometryExtension::flag2str[ExternalGeometryExtension::Frozen] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine with: 
clang version 5.0.0 and
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4

It fails to compile with MSVC2013.

The compilation error is:

```
 C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod/Sketcher/App/ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ';' [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod/Sketcher/App/ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod/Sketcher/App/ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'flag2str' [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod/Sketcher/App/ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2838: 'array<char const *,5>' : illegal qualified name in member declaration [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod/Sketcher/App/ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod/Sketcher/App/ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\ExternalGeometryExtension.cpp(36): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'std::array<const char *,0x05>' [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\ExternalGeometryExtension.cpp(36): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\ExternalGeometryExtension.cpp(36): error C2039: 'flag2str' : is not a member of 'Sketcher::ExternalGeometryExtension' [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         c:\projects\freecad\src\mod\sketcher\app\ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ';' [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         c:\projects\freecad\src\mod\sketcher\app\ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         c:\projects\freecad\src\mod\sketcher\app\ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'flag2str' [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         c:\projects\freecad\src\mod\sketcher\app\ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2838: 'array<char const *,5>' : illegal qualified name in member declaration [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         c:\projects\freecad\src\mod\sketcher\app\ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         c:\projects\freecad\src\mod\sketcher\app\ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod/Sketcher/App/ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ';' [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod/Sketcher/App/ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod/Sketcher/App/ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'flag2str' [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod/Sketcher/App/ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2838: 'array<char const *,5>' : illegal qualified name in member declaration [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod/Sketcher/App/ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod/Sketcher/App/ExternalGeometryExtension.h(47): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
         C:\projects\freecad\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\ExternalGeometryExtensionPyImp.cpp(67): error C2039: 'flag2str' : is not a member of 'Sketcher::ExternalGeometryExtension' [C:\projects\freecad\build\src\Mod\Sketcher\App\Sketcher.vcxproj]
```

Full compiler output [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/yorikvanhavre/freecad/builds/23534621/job/7eq48dqj27ixcllu)

My questions are: 
What I am doing wrong? Why is it not compiling with MSVC2013?

Is there something I can do to make this code work with MSVC2013 without breaking it in the other compilers?

EDIT: I have changed the code so that it is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as requested by Toby Speight based on the good guess of Diodacus. I cannot produce the error output of that specific code, because I do not have a copy of MSVC2003. I work on an opensource, FreeCAD, which offers Windows support. I use Linux. In any case, the errors in the output correspond to the code I show. This is the output of the AppVeyor test before integration. The code passes the Linux CI fine. I am going to try to make the most of this question, hopping that it is useful for others.

EDIT 2: I have realised that the double bracket initialization has raised some eyebrows. From the example in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

> double-braces required in C++11 prior to the CWG 1270 revision
>   (not needed in C++11 after the revision and in C++14 and beyond)

Without double braces gcc 4.8 fails.

Comment: MSVC2013 is old. And its support for c++11 was incomplete. MS didn't really have a decent C++11-able compiler until fairly recently.

Comment: As daily VS2013 user, I know only two options: Prevent "new" stylish features of C++ or `#ifdef` an alternative VS2013 compliant code. Both options are unsatisfying... ;-)

Comment: The code you show doesn't even *have* 36 lines, so those error messages cannot have come from it.  Please include a [mcve] and the *corresponding* error messages.

Comment: @Scheff You answered the last question. I have thought of this option. As you indicate it is unsatisfying. I will probably drop the constexpr and move the definition outside the class. Thanks you.

Comment: @Toby Speight I have edited the question to make a fully working example with the help of Diodacus. As I indicate in the question now, I do not have access to the actual error messages of this reduced example. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per this [microsoft devblog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c1114-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp/), `constexpr` is one of the C++11 core language features that is not supported in VS 2013. And it is only partially supported in "Nov 2013 CTP."

Comment: Yes, it answers my question. The code is c++11 compliant, but MSVC2013 does not support the full standard. I was not able to find this answer on my own. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the code in question does compile with C++17 option:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class ExternalGeometryExtension
{
public:
    enum Flag {
        Defining = 0,
        Frozen = 1, 
        Detached = 2,
        Missing = 3,
        Sync = 4,
        NumFlags
    };

    constexpr static std::array<const char *,NumFlags> flag2str{{ "Defining", "Frozen", "Detached","Missing", "Sync" }};
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << ExternalGeometryExtension::flag2str[ExternalGeometryExtension::Frozen] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And there is no need to redeclare static variable outside the class.

@Abdullah Tahiri Please use C++11 constructs (as stated in question labels) or go C++17 for all features. But I am afraid MSVC might be problematic with the code. Is there any special reason you cannot use GCC or CLang on Windows ?

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up/completing the code. I have used your example in the question so that it is clear in future reference. I think all my constructs are C++11 standard compliant. Replying to your question, this code is for a relatively big project, FreeCAD, which currently uses MSVC2013 to generate Windows builds. I do not own a Windows machine. I do not know why we are using MSVC2013, but I will use your input to ask the person responsible. Thanks.